# Update query in a huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mysql db for my application.I have one table with 40 million rows data.I want to run one update query in this table.Table contains three fields.Id,TaxiId,date&distance.I want to update distance to zero for particular Taxiid's.I am using one query like this

```
 update abc set distance=0 where TaxiId in(2026,2031,2033,2035,2037,2039);
```

When using explain I am getting below result

```
 id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
 1  SIMPLE  abc range   abc_trip_fk abc_trip_fk 5       1916397 Using where
```

Table Declare

```
   CREATE TABLE  `testdb`.`abc` (
 `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TaxiId` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 `distance` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY `trip_fk` (`TaxiId`) USING BTREE,
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=125127797 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I run this query entire application hangs.

Comment: Is TaxiID indexed? How big is the table?

Comment: how many rows are there? this seems weird to me.

Comment: You should check `EXPLAIN SELECT distance FROM abc where TaxiId in(2026,2031,2033,2035,2037,2039)` and see what's happening

Comment: rows need to updated may be 1 lakh.TaxiId is foriegn key

Comment: i think the most relevant question is the percentage of rows that respects the condition and if that `TaxiId` column is indexed

Comment: Can you post the table declare and (as suggested by @AlmaDoMundo) the EXPLAIN

Comment: TaxiId is not indexed.

Comment: Put an index on TaxiId.

Comment: I have updated question with result when using explain

Comment: Looks like it is doing a table scan over about 2m records. Post the table declare

Comment: If you are doing this for a massive number of TaxiIds then it might be worth setting up a temp table, inserting the taxi ids into that temp table and then doing an INNER JOIN between the abc table and the temp table in the update, avoiding the need for the massive IN clause.

Comment: @Kickstart declare updated in question

Comment: You need to add a key on TaxiId in that table. It appears you have about 125m records on that table, and MySQL has no way to find which of those records you want to update short of checking each on individually. An index will likely massively increase the performance of that query.

Comment: @Kickstart..updated question " KEY `trip_fk` (`TaxiId`) USING BTREE,"

Comment: @ Alma Do Mundo ..updated question with explain

Comment: I have just set up a copy of your table with 5.5m random records on it and using that for just selecting those records takes 0.13 seconds. Increased that to 12.5m records (with a heavy bias to taxid between 2000 and 2100), and the query takes 0.9 seconds bringing back 400k records. Doing the update on this does take a while (226 seconds to update 400k records). Beginning to wonder if it is just down to the number of records you are updating.

Comment: @Kickstart.may be mysql configuration

Comment: actually query that i tried having 24 TaxiId's in "IN" query

Comment: i think better option may be split IN query

Comment: i splitted it to 4 queries with in queries.then it works very fastlly.Also i put where condition that id >.

Answer (score 0):

Innodb buffer pool option is very important option for mysql performance.
Try to make following settings
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25GB

Disable indexes while insert/update/delete operation in database.
For more about mysql performance setting [find here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/)